# How does each browser choose the image url in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I'm running wordpress with the theme maidenhair and facing suddenly the problem that each browser chooses automatically the source url of the images independent from the url in the post where the photo has been inserted!

For example, I uploaded a picture called "IMG-20180419-WA0009.png" (it has the dimensions: 561 pixels * 790 pixels and the resolution 72.009 Pixels/Inch). 
Automatically two other versions of the file have been created by wordpress (with two another sizes to support the responsive pictures), namely: "IMG-20180419-WA0009-75x106.png" and "IMG-20180419-WA0009-150x150.png", because these are the dimensions which I set in the settings of the media sizes wordpress.

In the post where the picture is inserted I have adjusted the size to be like the following screenshot:
[Post_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwZoI.jpg)

Then when I surf the website from Mozilla Firefox, the photo appears correct, sharp, clear and with high quality, like the following screenshot:
[Firefox_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnlse.jpg)

Because the source url of the photo looks like:
[ImageURL_Firefox_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EhwE.jpg)

But if I surf the website using Google Chrome, the photo appears unsharp, blurry and with low quality, like the following screenshot:
[Chrome_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FeXU.jpg)

Because the source url of the photo is set automatically to the url of one of the smaller verions, it looks like:
[ImageURL_Chrome_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXBBm.jpg)

And sometimes exactly the contrary happens! I upload a photo, then Google Chrome pulls it from the correct url but Mozilla Firefox decides simply to pull it from an another file!

Comment: Please post the full HTML of the <img> tag, and the template part. It may be some `src-set` attributes on your image that allow browser to select from different URL (image sizes) of your file depending browser size.

Comment: <img class="aligncenter wp-image-4739" src="https://********.***/wp-content/uploads/IMG-20180419-WA0009.png" alt="IMG-20180419-WA0009" width="119" height="168" srcset="https://********.***/wp-content/uploads/IMG-20180419-WA0009.png 561w, https://********.***/wp-content/uploads/IMG-20180419-WA0009-75x106.png 75w" sizes="(max-width: 119px) 100vw, 119px" />

Answer (score 0):

As seen from your `<img>` tag dump, your theme (or plugin, or server optimization) is adding `src-set` attributes.

You can read more about the [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images).

As we see, `src` is the same for both Chrome and Firefox. It's possible that both browsers don't handle exactly the same src-set. But I'm pretty sure that the pixelized image you see come from one of the URL provided in `src-set`.

So :

- To be certain that issue comes from `src-set`, you could try to edit your template to remove `src-set` attributes and leave only `src`. Then check image rendering on both browsers.
- Edit your `src-set` while testing to see what is the one messing with one browser